# Placer la préposition « de » s'impose-t-il dans l'expression « se souvenir/rappeler d'avoir fait ... » ?

Tags: prépositions

Je crois avoir rencontré la structure « se souvenir/rappeler d'avoir fait ... » tout aussi souvent que la version omettant « de ».

> Je ne me souviens pas **d'avoir** jamais été déçu par cet acteur.
>
> Je ne me souviens pas **avoir** jamais été déçu par cet acteur.
>
> Je ne me rappelle pas **d'avoir** jamais été déçu par cet acteur.
>
> Je ne me rappelle pas **avoir** jamais été déçu par cet acteur.

Comment: À : @Gilles & Laure Je ne me suis pas rendu compte que c'est le genre de questions sur lesquelles même des locuteurs natifs se lancent dans des débats. Merci.

Comment: Merci à toi de l'avoir posée. Et de plus nos réponses sont en partie complémentaires, alors que visiblement on était en train de rédiger en même temps. Répondre à des questions intéressantes c'est enrichissant pour tout le monde.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En principe, le verbe *se souvenir* a un complément d'objet indirect introduit par *de*, et le verbe *se rappeler* a un complément d'objet direct (c'est-à-dire sans préposition).

> Je **me souviens de** cet acteur. Je **m'en souviens**.
>   Je **me rappelle** cet acteur. Je **me le rappelle**.

On trouve aussi « je me rappelle de cet acteur », « je m'en rappelle ». Les puristes considèrent que c'est une faute, mais c'est débattable : si c'était une faute, elle est si fréquemment commise par les locuteurs natifs qu'on devrait la considérer comme correcte. [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/rappeler), qui date du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle et est très conservateur, l'interdit (remarque 2). Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rappeler), qui est descriptiviste, cite « se rappeler de, s'en rappeler » comme « par analogie avec *se souvenir de* » et remarque que « les grammairiens condamnent la tournure […] que l'on trouve pourtant fréquemment chez les bons auteurs ». Je recommande d'éviter dans un devoir de français.

Dans les deux cas, le complément peut être une proposition à l'indicatif. Il n'y a alors pas de préposition.

> Je **me souviens que** cet acteur m'a déçu.
>   Je **me rappelle que** cet acteur m'a déçu.

Si la proposition principale est négative, la subordonnée est au subjonctif : « je ne me souviens/rappelle pas que cet acteur ne m'ait plu ».

Lorsque le sujet de la proposition subordonnée est le même que celui de la proposition relative, on met le verbe à l'infinitif dans la subordonnée, comme d'habitude. Dans ce cas, on met en principe la même préposition (ou absence de préposition) que si le complément était un nom.

> Je **me souviens d'avoir** été déçu par cet acteur.   [ou : **me souviens avoir**]
>   Je **me rappelle avoir** été déçu par cet acteur.   [ou : **me rappelle d'avoir**]

Ici l'usage est plus flottant : les deux verbes se trouvent avec ou sans *de*. Même Littré déclare que « des grammairiens condamnent se rappeler de avec un infinitif ; mais il est donné par l'usage, par les auteurs et par l'Académie ». Le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/souvenir) présente « se souvenir + infinitif passé » comme « par analogie avec *se rappeler* », et déclare « se rappeler de + infinitif passé » comme « vieilli ». Contrairement au cas où le complément est un nom, où le débat court encore, je pense qu'on peut considérer qu'avec un infinitif, les deux verbes se construisent au choix avec ou sans *de*.

Answer (score 3):

La question porte sur les verbes *se rappeler* et *se souvenir* suivi d'un **infinitif passé**.

**Se rappeler**
Les avis sur l'usage de la préposition « de » pour introduire un infinitif passé qui suit le verbe *se rappeler* étant divergents je vais citer *Le Bon usage*

> Lorsque le complément de *se rappeler* est un infinitif, cet infinitif n'est pas dans l'usage ordinaire d’aujourd’hui, précédé de *de*. 
>   Je me rappelle avoir vu...
>   La construction *je me rappelle* de + infinitif, signalée encore par Littré et par la 7e édition du Dictionnaire de l'Académie (1878) est aujourd'hui vieillie. (Grevisse, 10e édition, § 599, 22. et § 757, 6.)

Je pense que [cette page](https://rouleaum.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/se-rappeler-de-1/) résume assez bien la polémique. Polémique probablement dû au fait que quand il est suivi d'un nom « se rappeler » se construit avec un complément d'objet direct(se rappeler quelque chose).

---

**Se souvenir**

Je cite encore *Le bon usage* :

> Se souvenir demande régulièrement *de* devant l'infinitif complément.
>   *Il ne me souvient au lycée, d'avoir trouvé le moindre plaisir à étudier Virgile ou Racine.* (François Mauriac, *Le nœud de vipère*,1932).
>   [...]
>   Cependant sous l'influence du synonyme *se rappeler*, se souvenir se fait couramment suivre d'un infinitif sans préposition : *Je me souviens l'avoir promené*... (A. Daudet) (Grevisse, 10e édition, § 758, 6.)

On lira avec intérêt ce que dit La Banque de dépannage linguistique de l'Office québécois de la langue française sur ce sujet que je trouve pour le moins complexe : [Se rappeler et se souvenir](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2881).

Personnellement je dis :

> Je ne me souviens pas d'avoir jamais été déçu par cet acteur.
>   Je ne me rappelle pas avoir jamais été déçu par cet acteur.

Tout en sachant que tout le monde ne dit pas comme moi, et il est fort probable que la situation aura évolué dans 50 ans.